# Google Data Studio: How to combine trailing slash + non-trailing slash URLs?

Tags: regex, google-analytics, dashboard, looker-studio

I'm using Google Data Studio to create a dashboard for my Google Analytics data.

I'm trying to find the number of users visiting a `Page`, so I used Regex as seen:

[image: 1]

But instead I got 2 urls (trailing slash & non-trailing slash) - screenshot:

[image: 2]

Leading me to...

**My 2 questions:**

1. How do I combine both urls into 1 url?
2. And is it possible to apply this (combining trailing slash & non-trailing slashing urls) as a rule across all urls?

Comment: Please give a new picture, I can't read this one (the first), And it's the best if you write the regex as text, too.

Answer (score 6):

It can be achieved by using the [`REGEXP_REPLACE`](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7067058) [Calculated Field](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/6299685) below (which removes the last `/` (trailing forward slash) when it's present):

```
REGEXP_REPLACE(Page, "(/)$", "")
```

[Editable Google Data Studio Report](https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/fb4c04ed-6a16-4564-a954-4d35063e3f99) (Embedded [Google Sheets](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1oh6HzhXkuBqV3XFvFme90Mzcb7JLH8-Mos-ODUfnOvA/edit?usp=sharing) Data Source) and a GIF to elaborate:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could create a new dimension and use `REGEXP_REPLACE` to remove the trailing slashes.

```
REGEXP_REPLACE(Page,"/$","")
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have unique page titles for the pages in question, you can use that dimension instead of using page and creating a regex replace fx to combine into one. Using page titles also combines data for 1 URL with different parameters.

Comment: Upvote for the suggestion as this works well in GA too. However, it doesn't actually answer the question.